# Shift one char from string every second

Tags: javascript, html

for learning purpose i'm trying to move an `<p>` tag innerHTML by one char every second. I managed to move it, but i can't set that delay between moves. It just moves it instantly.

```
function shiftAChar(str) {
    charToShift = str[str.length - 1];
    return charToShift + "" + str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
    console.log(str);
    setTimeout(shiftAChar, 1000);
}

function shiftString(str) {
    for (i = 0; i <= 40; i++) {
        console.log(str);
        str = shiftAChar(str);
        document.getElementById("divSecundar").getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = str;
    }
}




window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("runEffect").addEventListener("click", function () {
        str = document.getElementById("divSecundar").getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML;
        console.log(str);
        shiftString(str);
    });
    document.getElementById("stopEffect").addEventListener("click", function () { run = false; })
}
```

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Nu are</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="evenimente.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <h2>Header Two</h2>
    <div>
        <div id="divSecundar">
            <p>Aceasta este primul paragraf</p>
            <p>Aceasta este al treilea</p>
        </div>
        <p>Aceasta este cel de-al doilea paragraf</p>
    </div>
    <input type="text" value="asdf" id="textBoxInput" />
    <input type="button" value="Run effect" id="runEffect" />
    <input type="button" value="Stop effect" id="stopEffect" />
    <input type="button" value="Animatie" id="animatie" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Click" id="btnClick" />
    <input type="button" value="Click" id="btnClickRemove" />

</body>
</html>
```

I don't want to use jQuery. Can it be achived using only pure javascript code?

My solution :

```
function shiftAChar(str) {
    charToShift = str[str.length - 1];
    return charToShift + "" + str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
}

function shiftString(str, counter) {
    if (counter <= 5) {
        str = shiftAChar(str);
        document.getElementById("divSecundar").getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = str;
        setTimeout(function () {
            shiftString(str, ++counter);
        }, 1000);
    }
}




window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("runEffect").addEventListener("click", function () {
        str = document.getElementById("divSecundar").getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML;
        console.log(str);
        shiftString(str, 0);
    });
}
```

Comment: You could use `setInterval(shiftString,1000);` to achieve that

Comment: Also you have a return statement in  `shiftAChar` followed by more code, the code after return will not be reached.

Comment: If you used a competent editor with syntax checking, or used a lint-like program to check your code, it would tell you about the unreachable code after the `return` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're close.  Specifically you don't want to do this in a loop per se, but instead you'd pseudo-recursively call the function using `setTimeout` (as you're attempting).  I think the problem you're finding is that the loop and the `setTimeout` attempt are *both* trying to do the same thing, and the loop is simply doing it faster.

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume the logic to move a character from one element to the other is encapsulated in the function `moveOneCharacter()`.  (This would include the actual UI updating.)  Since you already know how to make that work, this answer can just focus on the *timing* problem.

Structurally, the overall process might look something like this:

```
function shiftTheNextCharacter() {
    moveOneCharacter();
    if (charactersRemain()) {
        setTimeout(shiftTheNextCharacter, 1000);
    }
}
```

No loop needed.  Once you call this `shiftTheNextCharacter()` function, it will move the first character.  If there are any more characters (you'd have to write that function too, of course), it schedules itself to shift the next one.

This assumes there's always at least one character to start, of course.  You can modify the logic accordingly.  But the point of the structure is that a *loop* will do things instantly, whereas scheduling operations to happen at a later time gives you control over that timing.

Comment: not sure what charactersRemain() should do. What I really try to achive it's something like you see on TV down, the news feed.

Comment: @CiucaS: It would check if there are still characters to move, so the function isn't scheduled if there's nothing for it to do.  I guess it's not clear to me what effect you're going for.  I thought you were looking to move text from one element to another one character at a time.  I assumed that once the text is completely moved the process would be finished.

Comment: Something like there is on news channel, like CNN there is a bar down on the screen that keeps feeding you news, when there are no news left it starts all over again. Something like that, but i want to do that to a simple `<p>`

Comment: @CiucaS: So there is no end to the loop?  In that case you can remove the check for completion entirely and just use `setTimeout` pseudo-recursively like that.  The `if` condition is just to check when it should stop.  If it should never stop, then there's no need for the condition.

Comment: i used the loop just to test if it works for a few times. Anyways I've got the solution